# How to change display name of admin side menu of nopcommerce

Tags: asp.net-core, nopcommerce, nopcommerce-4.1

Screenshot of the issue:
[image]

I want to change the display name.

- What I did so far:

Added this line to `sidemap.config`

```
<siteMapNode SystemName="Customer reports" nopResource="Admin.Reports.Customers" PermissionNames="ManageCustomers" controller="Report" action="Customers" IconClass="fa-dot-circle-o" />
```

and

Added this line to `defaultResources.nopres.xml`

```
 <LocaleResource Name="Admin.Reports.Rewords">
    <Value>Reword Reports</Value>
  </LocaleResource>
```

I was reading this blog : http://lateshtclick.com/blogpost/adding-a-new-menu-item-in-admin-panel

But it does not work! :(

I'm use NopCommerce 4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default resources are added to the database on nopCommerce installation, thus if you're trying to add any entry programmatically, you would need to add that record to the DB too. To check if required resource is available or not:

Goto  admin > configuration > Languages > English(default) > Edit > String resources tab
And try to search with Resource name `Admin.Reports.Rewords`, you would be found that record is not present, now add it manually by Add new button, and check it admin menu.

Hope this helps!